# Does NSUserDefaults delete keys, that are not needed temporarily?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I'm storing all my data in NSUserDefaults. 
Now I'm trying to store some keys with a specific prefix in an Array. Therefore, I first load the UserDefaults in a Dictionary.

```
NSString *myPrefix = @"prefix";
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *dict = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
for (NSString *keyWithPrefix in dict.keyEnumerator) {
    if ([keyWithPrefix hasPrefix: myPrefix]) {
        [relevantKeys addObject: keyWithPrefix];
    }
}
```

The Problem is: when I print "dict" (which represents UserDefaults). There are some keys missing.
Does NSUserDefaults delete keys, that are not needed temporarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope it does not, NSUserDefault is a persistance storage, 
Please read the following answer it has a very good explanation
[How persistent is [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133127/how-persistent-is-nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

No, but are you calling `[NSUserdefaults synchronize]` when you are updating them ?

Comment: ok thanks, my mistake.. The keys, I was searching for, where never written into UserDefaults. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using `-synchronize` method when storing what you want. i,e:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:someDictionary forKey:@"someKey"];
[[NSUSerDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: No, unless you're coordinating with a different process that's reading the same preferences (which is unusual), you should not need to invoke `-synchronize`.