# iOS4 reset app push notification settings

Tags: iphone, ios4, apple-push-notifications

I need to reset the push notification settings of one app on the iPhone.

The path " /private/var/mobile/Library/RemoteNotification/Clients.plist " mentionned in this thread " [Reset push notification settings for app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app) " seems to have changed since iOS4.

Does anyone know of to reset/remove the push notification settings for one specific application on the iPhone iOS4? Where the file containing this information is stored?

Answer (score 1):

Two days I tried to find solution (I installed old version of safari download manager and one unknown notification appeared on Safari icon. Nothig helped me either reinstalling of SDM or installing of new version etc.)

Guys, there is the one:

**/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/applicationstate.plist**

The magic strings have been found very quickly:

```
    <key>com.apple.mobilesafari</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SBApplicationBadgeKey</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
```

Integer value has been replaced on zero succesfully

After that you need to restart SpringBoard, otherwise your changes in this file will be lost!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

In ios 5 you should enter via ifile to

/var/mobile/library/springboard/
then enter to applicationstate.plist in propietes visor
then you look in the list for the aplication you want to reset and delete the entry

And Voila, the next time you enter the aplication is going to ask you if you want to recive notifications