# Reset Push Notification settings for alert

Tags: iphone, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have developed an app that enabled push notification. It is available in AppStore. After installing the application on my device it shows Alert for enabling push notification sometimes only. Is that an issue from my side?.

In the case that once I did "Use" action and after some days I deleted app from my device. Will the alert for allowing push notification be asked the next I download it from AppStore.

Issue is like once I give "Use/Cancel", and deleted the app from device, on next download it is not asking whether you interested use push notification or not.

Please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I got answer for this question from the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.Delete your app from the device.

2.Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.

3.Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.

4.Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

for reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

See the [Apple technical note TN2265](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html). In section *"Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS"* they explain how to reset the permission dialog on iOS. However many developers complain that the procedure doesn't work. See [my response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191006/objective-c-detect-when-user-change-the-apps-notifications-settings/10191220#10191220) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in IOS 10 and development environment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

is enough to uninstall the app and rerun it and the push notification permission alert is shown on every ne install.