# How do I force the iOS push notification dialog to show up (for testing)?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clear preference iOS push notifications for my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959629/how-to-clear-preference-ios-push-notifications-for-my-application)

How do I force the iOS alert view that says "[AppName] would like to send you push notifications?" It never shows after the first time.

I want to do this for testing, we found a problem in our app where the alert view showed and caused a problem in a flow of view controllers.

Comment: See [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780795/reset-push-notification-settings-for-alert/10207040#10207040) to a similar question and more about the issue in general in [another response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191006/objective-c-detect-when-user-change-the-apps-notifications-settings). In short there is a procedure outlined by Apple in [technical note TN2265](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html), but it looks like it not always works.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a similar question:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959629/how-to-clear-preference-ios-push-notifications-for-my-application/10208336#comment13113717_10208336][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959629/how-to-clear-preference-ios-push-notifications-for-my-application/10208336#comment13113717_10208336

Answer (score -3):

You'll have to delete the app and install it again.

Comment: Does not work, I still don't get the uialertview a second time

Comment: If not, then you'll have to change BundleIDs of your app.