# iOS: How to completely delete an app from a device for debugging purposes

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm attempting test an app that uses push notifications. I would like to test the result of various scenarios that result from the user selecting either "allow" or "don't allow" from the intital dialog that appears. However, I am only shown this dialog once.

Even after I delete the app from the device, from the organizer, from itunes, and clean the project, it will not show me this dialog when I reinstall. How can I get this app erased so I can receive this dialog again?

Comment: You may need to wait 24 hours for the dialog to appear again.  Would the answers [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959629/how-to-clear-preference-ios-push-notifications-for-my-application) help you out??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for 24 hours to get iOS to remove all data and settings from the device, if you have a special development device (which you should have, by the way), an easier way is probably to simply make a clean install of iOS in Xcode (it doesn't work if you restore your device, so that might not be an option if you use the device not only for development)

Comment: Wow. It seems like should be an easier way to do this for development purposes.

Comment: @JamesHarpe Agreed, but sadly there is no easier way to do this. However, you should file a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) for this to get more attention on this (it will be closed as duplicate, but the more people filing a bug, the more attention it will receive (in theory)).