# Push Notification ON or OFF Checking in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to check "Push Notification option" in iOS device, any time if the application is running (or ON from resume mode). I use the following code to check, if the option is OFF:

```
-(void)PushNotificationServiceChecking
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];

    if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
    {
        NSString *msg = @"Please press ON to enable Push Notification";
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Push Notification Service Disable" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ON", nil];
        alert.tag = 2;
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Then i use the following code for going to the "Settings tab >> Notification center", so that user can on it manually :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 2)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            // this is the cancel button
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
        }
    }

}
```

But, now the problem that I am facing is, it only appears at the 1st time after launching the application. It works as I want. But after that, if I turn OFF the "Push Notification option" from "settings" it gives me no "Alert Message".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the App once got registered with the `registerForRemoteNotification`, then you can disable as well as enable . Once you disable and you are about to Re-Regigister with it, then this will enable the  `registerForRemoteNotification`, without Popup for a alert.

[Technical Note TN2265: Troubleshooting Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

> The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS
>   asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once
>   the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless
>   the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a
>   day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave
>   the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without
>   actually waiting a day by setting the system clock forward a day or
>   more, turning the device off completely, then turning the device back
>   on.

Fore More Info: [INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033216/how-to-show-would-like-to-send-you-push-notifications-alert-view-again) && [Info 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app?lq=1)

**Edit** : For `checking with alert enable` -

use

```
 if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert){}
```

instead of

```
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone){}
```

**Edit :**
Latest update from the [doc for iOS 8 or later](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications), You can check out by :

```
- (BOOL)isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
```

Comment: Yes, it is. But, after once `registerForRemoteNotification`, it couldn't detect the "Push Notification option" is ON or OFF second time. How can i detect that every time, if my application is running. That's the problem. Thanks for commenting. @Kumar Ki

Comment: Whenever your app get launches Do the **registerForRemoteNotificationTypes** Then automatically its get enabled

Comment: What exactly you are doing is that, You are just disable the alerts Not the Disabling with the **RemoteNotification**. So that mean, The app has already registered for it., So **if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)** gets false

Comment: yes, i got it. But i have to check, is the device "Push Notification option" ON or OFF for my particular application or For the whole device? Though my application is registered for "Push Notification".

Comment: Check with this **UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
one can use

if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert){}**

Comment: Nope, i am trying with `UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]; one can use if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert){}`
The "AlertView" showing every time, if i turn on "Push Notification"

And also try with `UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]; one can use if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert){}`
But it behaves the same.
Thanks for your all effort dear @Kumar KI. This is really full of information which is really appreciable. :)

Answer (score 41):

In iOS 8 you can now use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
```

And to check how the settings are setup you could use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

Comment: For the record: if user disabled notifications or pressed 'don't allow', `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications` will still be true the next time.

Comment: If user pressed Don't allow, isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications seems to return false.

Answer (score 8):

It's work for me. Hope this help! :D

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)


if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){
    UIUserNotificationType type = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings] types];
    if (type == UIUserNotificationTypeNone){
        ALERT_WITH_TITLE(@"", kMessageNotificationTurnOnRequire);
    }
}
else {
   UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
   if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
       ALERT_WITH_TITLE(@"", kMessageNotificationTurnOnRequire);
   }
}
```

Comment: i think some comments might make it easier to understand than `ALERT_WITH_TITLE(@"", kMessageNotificationTurnOnRequire);` How about `//Push Notifications Are Disabled`

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *iOSversion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
NSString *prefix = [[iOSversion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] firstObject];
float versionVal = [prefix floatValue];

if (versionVal >= 8)
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings].types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone)
    {
        NSLog(@" Push Notification ON");
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *msg = @"Please press ON to enable Push Notification";
        UIAlertView *alert_push = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Push Notification Service Disable" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Setting", nil];
        alert_push.tag = 2;
        [alert_push show];

        NSLog(@" Push Notification OFF");
    }
}
else
{
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types != UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
    {
        NSLog(@" Push Notification ON");
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *msg = @"Please press ON to enable Push Notification";
        UIAlertView *alert_push = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Push Notification Service Disable" message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Setting", nil];
        alert_push.tag = 2;
        [alert_push show];

        NSLog(@" Push Notification OFF");
    }
}
```