# Check if user accepted a push notification permission in iOS in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

How can I check if the user denied or accepted the push notification permission message in ios in codenameone or native?

Comment: Please do not go ALL CAPS on us.

Comment: I would be remiss if i didn't ask you but: have you tried to write that same question on google first?

Comment: yes, I found so much but in codenameone it don't appear nothing related

Answer (score 0):

Both Android and iOS have API's to detect if push is enabled:
[Push Notification ON or OFF Checking in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374801/push-notification-on-or-off-checking-in-ios)

[Android 4.1: How to check notifications are disabled for the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application)

Since those were added relatively recently and we didn't get enough demand for that we don't support them at this time. You can probably invoke them with a native interface or submit a pull request with integration. Normally you would get a push registered callback when push works and an error or nothing if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution implementing a funtion native to IOS 10

This methods are working perfectly in Objective-c and codenameone code

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//This method is use to check if the user enable or disable push notification
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-(BOOL)isPushNotificationIsEnable{

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]) {
        NSLog(@"isPushNotificationIsEnable()->YES");
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"isPushNotificationIsEnable()->NO");
        return NO;
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//This method is use to launch the Notification screen of your app
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Display.getInstance().execute("App-Prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=your package name app", new ActionListener() {
     String methodName = "startLocationSetting";
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            boolean status = Utils.isPushNotificationEnable();

      }

});
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```