# NewsStand, Show the push notification alert view when I want?

Tags: ios, push-notification, uialertview, newsstand-kit

I know this has been asked: [How to show "Would like to send you Push Notifications" Alert View again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033216/how-to-show-would-like-to-send-you-push-notifications-alert-view-again) ... But My question is kind of different. My question is that is it possible to prompt this when ever I want programmatically (not for debugging but for real). Probably not because this is an alert triggered by the operating system, but is there a way to "undo" if a user clicked "don't allow". My app has a tutorial I want to pop this message when the user finishes the tutorial. Should I just register for push notifications after the tutorial?. Or what the user has to "allow" on the settings menu so I can add it to the tutorial. Thanks

[image: alert notification]

Answer (score 1):

To trigger popup you provide on image you should call

```
[[UIApplicaton sharedApplication]   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability]
```

This is possible to do in any place in app.

To check available permissions use:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType* enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

Comment: Can you edit this to be clearer?  It doesn't make much sense to me as it stands.

Comment: how can i check the enabledTypes? it's a strange enum... how can I print them in a NSLog or something... in my case (enabledTypes == 7) is true

Comment: yep, bit fields a bit strange for first look, but read some manual about bits and bit shifts and all become clean

Comment: so basically you can trigger this alert when ever you want... but just once... that sucks...