# Push notification status for iOS8 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have been looking for a proper tutorial on setting push notification in Swift for iOS8 but I feel like a lot of changes have been made from Objective-C to Swift and iOS7 to iOS8, though I can't find any updated piece of code on that.

I am trying to know if the user has pushed the "Don't Allow" button in the Push Notification Alert and/**or if they ever saw it**.

The fact is that I would like, in that case, to show an alert asking the user to reallow notifications through settings.

Problem: I don't know which variable to check to know if I should show the popup or not.

I could use this but the hashvalue is at 0 in both cases where 1- push notification alert was never shown, 2- push notification alert was shown but user pushed "Don't Allow".

```
if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings().hashValue == 0){
            pushNotificationStatus = "false"
        } else {
            pushNotificationStatus = "true"
        }
```

Would you have any best practice/idea to solve this?
Thanks you!

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111644/detect-allow-notifications-is-on-off-for-ios8

Answer (score 0):

```
//Write belkow code in Appdelegate.m in didfinishLaunching mehod..

  Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {

  let types:UIUserNotificationType = (.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
  let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
  application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

} else {      
  // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
  application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(.Alert | .Badge | .Sound)
}
```

**you can get in didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError**

```
  func application(
        application: UIApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData
    ) {


         //Process the deviceToken and send it to your server
         let trimEnds = {
          deviceToken.description.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
          NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>"))
            }
         let cleanToken = {
          trimEnds.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
           " ", withString: "", options: nil)
           }
        }

    func application(
        application: UIApplication,
        didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError
    ) {
        //Log an error for debugging purposes, user doesn't need to know
        NSLog("Failed to get token; error: %@", error) 
    }
```

**On Receiving notification following delegate will call:**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    println("Recived: \(userInfo)")
   //Parsing userinfo:
   var temp : NSDictionary = userInfo
   if let info = userInfo["aps"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> 
            {
                var alertMsg = info["alert"] as! String
                var alert: UIAlertView!
                alert = UIAlertView(title: "", message: alertMsg, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
            }
}
```

**And You can control the hash value of UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings().**

```
if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))){
        if(UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings().hashValue == 0){
            pushNotificationStatus = "false"
        } else {
            pushNotificationStatus = "true"
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that does respond to my question. How do I know if the alert has been shown already or not?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10.0 you can use this method

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(completionHandler:  { settings in
     switch settings.authorizationStatus {
     case .notDetermined:
         print("Not determined")
     case .denied: //In this case user has already seen this alert, and answered "Don't allow"
         print("Denied") 
     case .authorized:
         print("Authorised")
}
```