# iOS device token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

If I accept push notification on my device, and do not save device token then how i can see device token in custom view or revert alert view ?

I deleted app and reinstalled, but  do not see device token alert view, and revoke permissions, but no see alert view

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
{
    // iOS 8 Notifications

    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
    else
{
    // iOS < 8 

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question.explain what is your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset push notification settings for app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's your problem based your question I think you are asked to not getting Push notification alert after delete or reinstalled app second time right?

By [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42)

The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.

If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:

- Delete your app from the device.
- Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
- Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
- Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

and more please read apple [push notification Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#push-notifications).