# How to simulate fresh installation on IOS8?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I have to simulate a fresh installation on IOS 8 including confirmation prompt for notification services.

I remove app from device and run from xcode, but it somehow remembers the application was here and doesn't give the prompt.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4080720/724514. It also contains a link to the tech note which has been updated as late as 2014.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset push notification settings for app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app)