# Permission for Notifications Dialog shows only once

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I would like to see again the Permission for Notifications Dialog in my app(https://i.stack.imgur.com/URnm0.png) to see if I got the timing right. I tried deleting the app, and running it again but iOS system remembers what the notification settings were before deletion. Is it possible to recreate that window somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset push notification settings for app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **give it at least 24 hours** after deleting the app to be able to recreate that Notification Permission alert view.

Or you can set your **phone's clock to tomorrow or 24 hours** ahead of time (within your settings) and try it.

or try running that same code through a **iOS simulator**