# Install hybrid not showing the opt-in notification message

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid app in my QA environment and we don't see the opt in notification message on any device when the app is install.. This work on my local machine that uses my local eclipse MFP..

I expect to see the prompt:

---

**"Rand jobs Would like to sent you notification**

Notification may include alert, sound

### these can be configured in Settings

Dont't Allow| OK

---

Can you please provide some hints on how to get this working again.. No phone are getting register...

I verify that certs and port are open..

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset push notification settings for app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same physical device during development and QA, and the same application ID?

This may be the issue: [Reset push notification settings for app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438400/reset-push-notification-settings-for-app)

The steps to reset iOS to recognize the app as a new app with push requests:

> 1. Delete your app from the device.
> 2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
> 3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
> 4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

Comment: Here is what i see in the console... Is it possible to have a quick look and let me know .. please

Comment: a background thread.
2016-05-23 06:57:54.750 RandstadJobs[273:9587] MFP detected environment: ios
https://qamfp.randstadusa.com:443/RandstadMobile/apps/services/api/RandstadRecruiter/iphone/init
2016-05-23 06:57:55.040 RandstadJobs[273:9587] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:363 :: Request Failed
2016-05-23 06:57:55.042 RandstadJobs[273:9587] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -

Comment: [WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:364 :: Response Status Code : 503
2016-05-23 06:57:55.045 RandstadJobs[273:9587] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:365 :: Response Error : Request failed: service unavailable (503)

Comment: 2016-05-23 06:57:55.061 RandstadJobs[273:9587] MFP: No Connection - {
  "status": 503,
  "errorCode": "UNEXPECTED_ERROR",
  "errorMsg": "The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later."
}
2016-05-23 06:57:55.061 RandstadJobs[273:9628] [ERROR] [NONE] [/apps/services/api/RandstadRecruiter/iphone/init] failure. state: 503, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the `WL.Server.sendMessage` method. The appName and `options` parameters are
  mandatory.
- Specify the `tagNames` as an array in the `options.target.tagNames` object. In
  Example, the tagNames sent in the procedure are in a loop to fill the
  `options.target.tagNames` array.
- Specify the message to be sent as text in `options.message.alert`.

For example :

```
  function submitNotification(appName, tagNames, message)
       {
           var options = {};
           options.message = {};
           options.message.alert = message;
           options.target = {};
           options.target.tagNames = [];
           for(var i=0; i<tagNames.length; i++){
           options.target.tagNames.push(tagNames[i]);
        }
          var delayTimeOut = WL.Server.sendMessage(appName, options);
          WL.Logger.warn("notificationTimeout"+delayTimeOut);
      }
```

source Book:

> Extending IBM Business
>   Process Manager to the Mobile
>   Enterprise with IBM Worklight